# Node.js spawn commands with backslash

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using spawn in node.js and in my command line arguments I need to have a backslash, like this `'scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:min(480\,iw)"'`  It seems like the backslash is getting removed from the command.  I've tried `\\` but no luck.  Any ideas how to maintain this single `\`.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the command you would run (if you were running manually in the shell)

Comment: There's a lot more to that command, I'd rather not post it all, but that snippet is the issue, which runs fine on command line, but not through node's spawn.

Comment: Have you tried double escaping it? \\\\

Comment: Ok, it turns out that the double backslash does in fact work `\\\`, however the quotes do not, so removing those fixed it.